# How do I invoke JavaScript in AjaxResponse?

Tags: 8

I'm submitting a form via AJAX.

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
```

It's not using the Drupal default dialog, so I can't use `$response->addCommand(new CloseModalDialogCommand());` after all validation is done. It's using jQuery Modal.

Validation is working fine. After all things done I want to execute Javascript in `submitForm` function.

Which function should I use? I need to check for example `alert(1)`.

I have to close window using Javascript & Alert message as well. I tried `AlertCommand` but not working.

Following this example: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Ajax%21InvokeCommand.php/class/InvokeCommand/8.2.x
But not working

I have below code

**modules/demo_test/src/Form/DemoTestForm.php**

```
namespace Drupal\demo_test\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;

class DemoTestForm extends FormBase {


  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {


    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="demo-test--modal-form">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['firstname'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('First name'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];

    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#name' =>'submit',
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::ajaxSubmitForm',
        'event' => 'click',
      ],
    ];

    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'demo_test/demo';

    return $form;
  }

  public function ajaxSubmitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    drupal_get_messages();

    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    if ($form_state->getErrors()) {
      unset($form['#prefix']);
      unset($form['#suffix']);
      $form['status_messages'] = [
        '#type' => 'status_messages',
        '#weight' => -10,
      ];
      $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#demo-test-modal-form', $form));
    }
    return $response;
  }

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'demo_test_form';
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $response = new AjaxResponse();
    $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('html', 'trigger', array(
      'triggerName',
      array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
      ),
    )));
    return $response;
  }
}
```

**modules/demo_test/js/demo.js**

```
(function ($, Drupal) {

  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.demo = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

      $(document).on('triggerName', function(e, data) {
        alert('data.foo'); // alerts string 'bar'
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery, Drupal);

jQuery(document).on('triggerName', function(e, data) {
    alert(1);
    alert('data.foo'); // alerts string 'bar'
});
```

It's not going in JS file & alert. JS file is loading fine.

Comment: You need to define what "not working" means and show your code. `InvokeCommand` definitely works and is exactly how you would communicate from an AjaxResponse to trigger any arbitrary Javascript function or method.

Comment: Also it is perfectly fine if you aren't using modals and JS UI elements that Drupal uses. You can go off and define 100 AjaxCommands of your own and do whatever you please, just like `CloseModalDialogCommand`. Two modules I wrote showing an example of this are iGrowl and SweetAlert. https://www.drupal.org/project/igrowl & https://www.drupal.org/project/sweetalert

Comment: @Kevin I added the code. Please look in to that

Comment: Whats with the function outside of your behavior scope?

Comment: Anyway I think what you are missing is that your function is not an extension of jQuery and cannot be called. See this comment on the doc page: https://api.drupal.org/comment/62911#comment-62911

Answer (score 4):

Best way is probably to add your own custom command :

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\demo_test\Ajax;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CommandInterface;
class DemoTestJsCommand implements CommandInterface
{
    public function render(){
        return [
            'command' => 'demoTestJsCommand',
        ];
    }

}
```

And JS :

```
Drupal.AjaxCommands.prototype.demoTestJsCommand = function (ajax, response) {
    alert(1);
};
```

Then, you just have to add

```
$response->addCommand(new DemoTestJsCommand());
```

in you form's response.